# Overloaded member function pointer to template

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to store member function pointers by templates like this: (This is a simplified version of my real code)

```
template<class Arg1>
void connect(void (T::*f)(Arg1)) 
{
    //Do some stuff
}

template<class Arg1>
void connect(void (T::*f)()) 
{
    //Do some stuff
}

class GApp
{
public:
    void foo() {}

    void foo(double d) {}
};
```

Then I want to do like the following for every overloaded methods in GApp:

```
connect(&GApp::foo);
```

Calling this for `foo()` is ok, but how can I call this for `foo(double d)`? Why isn't the following working?

```
connect((&GApp::foo)(double));
```

It will give me

> syntax error : 'double' should be preceded by ')'

I don't understand the syntax which must be used here. This may be a stupid qustion, but can any one help me on this?

Comment: It's a better idea to use Functors instead of function pointers imho.

Comment: The whole code is a part of implementation of a Signal and Slot mechanism. So, The litener (who has the slot) don't want to know about the system. So, I can't say to listener to do like this,do like this......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code as written doesn't compile.  I've make some "assumptions" about what you wanted to do, and have changed the code.

To summarise, you can call the correct function by explicitly specifying the function parameter type:

```
connect<double> (&GApp::foo);
```

If the connect methods are members of a class template, then it is only necessary to specify the class type once:

```
template <typename T> class A
{
public:
  template<class Arg1>
  void connect(void (T::*f)(Arg1)) 
  {
    //Do some stuff
  }

  void connect(void (T::*f)()) 
  {
    //Do some stuff
  }
};

class GApp
{
public:
    void foo() {}
    void foo(double d) {}
};


int main ()
{
  A<GApp> a;
  a.connect (&GApp::foo);            // foo ()
  a.connect<double> (&GApp::foo);    // foo (double)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to the new code sample, all the information is being passed in.  The "rare" case is the 'signal_void' case as this is where the signal has a template argument, but the member function doesn't.  Therefore we special case that example and then we're done.  The following now compiles:

```
template <class Arg = void>
class signal {};
signal<double> signal_double;
signal<> signal_void;

// Arg1 is deduced from signal<Arg1> and then we use it in the declaration
// of the pointer to member function
template<class T, class Arg1>
void connect ( signal<Arg1>& sig, T& obj, void (T::*f)(Arg1) ) {}

// Add special case for 'void' without any arguments
template<class T>
void connect (signal<> & sig, T& obj, void (T::*f)()) {}


void bar ()
{
  GApp myGApp;

  //Connecting foo()
  connect(signal_void, myGApp, &GApp::foo); // Matches second overload

  //Connecting foo(double)
  connect(signal_double, myGApp, &GApp::foo); // Matches first overload
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the effort. Sorry, I forgot to tell that my code isn't complete. It was because I removed Signal template class to simplify the code. BTW, yes, your method is working well. I'll post my original code, can you look at it then ? Thanks

Comment: Wohooooo.... yeah. You show me the path. Now all are working correctly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ Programming Language, 3E, Section 7.7, p159:

> You can take the address of an overloaded function by assigning to or initializing a pointer to function. In that case, the type of the target is used to select from the set of overloaded functions. For example:

```
void f(int);
int f(char);

void (*pf1)(int) = &f;  // void f(int);
int (*pf2)(char) = &f;  // int f(char);
void (*pf3)(char) = &f; // error: no void f(char)
```

As far as I know (haven't checked), the same applies to member functions. So the solution is probably to split across two lines:

```
connect((&GApp::foo)(double));
```

becomes:

```
void (GApp::*tmp)(double) = &GApp::foo;
connect(tmp);
```

Never call variables `tmp` ;-)

I would guess that newacct's cast is safe too, for exactly the same reason. Casting to `void (GApp::*)(double)` is defined to be the same as initializing a temporary of type `void (GApp::*)(double)`. Since the expression used to initialize it is `&GApp::foo`, I would expect the same magic to apply to the cast as applies to any other initialization with an overloaded function. Stroustrup doesn't say "initializing a pointer-to-function variable", he says "initializing a pointer-to-function". So that should include temporaries.

So if you prefer a one-liner:

```
connect((void (GApp::*)(double))(&GApp::foo));
```

However, I'm assuming that the standard has the same idea of consistency as I do, and I haven't checked.

Comment: And they say C++ is hard to understand! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try explicitly casting the pointer, to let it know which one to select, like this:

```
connect((void (GApp::*)(double))&GApp::foo);
```

disclaimer: haven't tested it

Comment: It can't be safe: a cast is merely a function on the GApp::foo pointer.  It won't change the content of the pointer.

Comment: I have a theory that it is safe, see my answer for details. I haven't confirmed it in the standard yet, though, because I have a strong suspicion the language in the standard will match Stroustrup's in C++PL anyway, and it's a slightly hair-splitting question.

Comment: My mistake - apparently this is the way to specify overloaded functions (see http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml?articleID=184406484&dept_url=/cpp/ , somewhere near the end)

Answer (score 0):

This is working,

```
    typedef void (GApp::*MemberFunctionType)(double); 
    MemberFunctionType pointer = &GApp::foo;


  connect(MemberFunctionType);
```

Why is that ?

EDIT

hmm.. yeah. It is same as newacct's solution. Can anyone give a solution pls?

Comment: My answer explains why this works, by reference to Stroustrup and an assumption that what he says about function pointers applies also to member function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Using boost::function library...

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

template<class Arg1>
void connect(boost::function1<void, Arg1*> fn) 
{
    //Do some stuff
}

template<class Arg1>
void connect(boost::function2<void, Arg1*, double> fn) 
{
    //Do some stuff
}

class GApp
{
public:
    void foo() {}

    void foo(double d) {}
};


int main()
{
    boost::function1<void,GApp*> f1 = (void (GApp::*)(void)) &GApp::foo;
    boost::function2<void,GApp*,double> f2 = (void (GApp::*)(double)) &GApp:foo;
    connect(f1);
    connect(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the ans. Isn't your (void (GApp::*)(double)) &GApp:foo; same as newacct's solution, (void (GApp::*)(double))&GApp::foo. But xtofl told that is isn't safe :(

Comment: xtofl has updated comment to say that it seems to be safe. Its preferable to use function objects rather than function pointers, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

My Original code is like this,

connectors....

```
template<class T, class Arg1>
void connect(signal<Arg1>& sig,T& obj, void (T::*f)()) 
{
//  sig.insert(new GFunction<T, Arg1>(&obj,f));
}

template<class T, class Arg1
void connect(signal<Arg1>& sig,T& obj, void (T::*f)(Arg1)) 
{
//  sig.insert(new GFunction<T, Arg1>(&obj,f));
}
```

Signals...

```
signal<double> signal_double;
signal<> signal_void;
```

Application...

```
class GApp
{
public:
    void foo() {}

    void foo(double d) {}
};
```

Finaly, connecting...

```
//Connecting foo()
        connect(signal_void, myGApp, &GApp::foo()); //Ok

//Connecting foo(double)
        connect(signal_double, myGApp, &GApp::foo()); // but ERROR!
```

There is template classs for signals (which are not mention here). I hope now it is more clear the situation. (or is it same as previouse ?). That second connection will WORK if there isn't foo() (only foo(double)). That is the thing my code hurt me. :(