# Template type deduction for a pointer to member function

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I have a very similar problem to that presented by Morpheus, in the following question:

[Overloaded member function pointer to template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096931/overloaded-member-function-pointer-to-template)

The solution proposed by Richard Corden requires the user to explicitly specify the function parameter type, to distinguish it among the overloads. However, this solution does not seem to work with overloads with a varying number of arguments of the **same type**.

Consider this example (derived from the original question):

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
  template<class Arg1>
  void connect(void (T::*f)(Arg1)) 
  {
    //Do some stuff
  }

  template<class Arg1, class Arg2>
  void connect(void (T::*f)(Arg1,Arg2)) 
  {
    //Do some stuff
  }

  void connect(void (T::*f)()) 
  {
    //Do some stuff
  }
};

class GApp
{
public:
    void foo() {}
    void foo(double d) {}
    void foo(double d1, double d2) {}
};


int main ()
{
  A<GApp> a;
  a.connect (&GApp::foo);                // foo () - OK
  a.connect<double> (&GApp::foo);        // foo (double) - FAIL
  a.connect<double,double> (&GApp::foo); // foo (double,double) - OK
}
```

GNU G++ 3.4.5 and MSVC 2008 do not compile the code above, both presenting similar  error messages:

```
test.cpp: In function `int main()':
test.cpp:36: error: call of overloaded `connect(<unknown type>)' is ambiguous
test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: void A<T>::connect(void (T::*)(Arg1)) [with Arg1 = double, T = GApp]
test3.cpp:13: note:               void A<T>::connect(void (T::*)(Arg1, Arg2)) [with Arg1 = double, Arg2 = double, T = GApp]
```

**I'm aware** of some workarounds that can make it compile, like assigning the pointer to a variable of the exact same type (e.g. `void (GApp::*tmp)(double) = &GApp::foo;`) or, using a more explicity form when calling the connect function (e.g. `connect((void (GApp::*)(double))(&GApp::foo));`).

However, I prefer the first solution and would like to know **why** it is not working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd actually be worried about the first one not failing. It's too easy to forget about the template arguments and have a wrong overload selected silently.

Comment: In your main(), only the second call, "a.connect<double>(&GApp::foo)" is not compiling. Why you have mentioned 3rd call also a fail ?

Comment: @iammilind, Sorry for that, I just misunderstood the error messages. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `a.connect<double> (&GApp::foo)`, both the `foo(double)` and `foo(double, double)` will match the overload of `connect` with one, and with two template parameters respectively (in the case of the two parameter version, the second template argument will be deduced, the first argument was provided by you explicitly).

If you want to disambiguate ambiguous cases, I recommend that you pass the exact type, so no surprises can happen. Instead of those overloads, why not have a single overload

```
template<typename MType, typename T>
void connect(MType T::*f) 
{
  //Do some stuff
}

a.connect<void()> (&GApp::foo);
a.connect<void(double)> (&GApp::foo);
a.connect<void(double, double)> (&GApp::foo);
```

The last call to `connect` should work fine in your code too. You then can dissect the type `MType` in `connect` with separate templates, to get the parameter and return types.

Comment: Nice! Actually, I just had a hard time trying to understand this template defition, didnt know it was even possible to define a function pointer like that (`MType T::f*`). Still, when using this approach, why the compiler is not able to deduct the function pointer type, even when there are no overloads?

Comment: @NCrawl, it should be able to deduce. I think MSVC++ may have problems with that. It would be a compiler bug then. It definitely is valid C++.

Comment: @litb Ok then, thank you very much! Just for the record, MSVC'08 was ok with that, only GNU GCC 3.4.5 could not deduce.

Comment: @NCrawl Apparently, neither msvc9 nor msvc10 is able to compile litb's sample code (of course after correcting it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original code is that you are explicitly defining the wrong part.  When you specify a list of template parameters, even when you specify one, the compiler will attempt to deduce the second one and then it runs right back into ambiguity because it doesn't know if you want to use (double,double) or (double) variation.

Instead of defining template parameters, let the compiler deduce them but explicitly specify which one of the foo() functions you want to use:

```
int main()
{
    A<GApp> a;
    a.connect (&GApp::foo);                                     // foo () - OK
    a.connect( ( void (GApp::*)(double) )&GApp::foo);           // foo (double) - OK
    a.connect( ( void (GApp::*)(double, double) ) &GApp::foo);  // foo (double,double) - OK
}
```