# How to pass a member function pointer to an overloaded method in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, pointer-to-member

I referred to this [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096931/overloaded-member-function-pointer-to-template). However here the scenario is different:

```
struct A
{
  void foo (int i) {} // choice
  void foo (double i) {}
};

template<typename ObjType, typename FuncPtr>
void ReceiveFuncPtr (ObjType o, FuncPtr pf)
{
 (o.*pf)(1);
}

int main ()
{
  A obj;
  ReceiveFuncPtr(obj, &A::foo); // don't want typecast here
}
```

In the above test code, I have an overloaded `foo` inside `A`. Had there been only 1 `foo` then the code works fine. But for overloading case, compiler complains as:

> error: no matching function for call
>   to `ReceiveFuncPtr(A&, [unresolved
>   overloaded function type])'

Instead of explicit typecasting while calling `ReceiveFuncPtr()`, is there any way that we can make some changes in its `template` parameter and enable it to receive `foo(int)` version always  for any similar `class A` ?

**Edit**: Idea is **not to worry about the type** while calling the function. It should be as simple as, `ReceiveFuncPtr(obj, &A::foo);` And let the `template` do its work.

Comment: Define what "for any similar class A" means, then one can better help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this:

```
template<typename ObjType>
void ReceiveFuncPtr (ObjType o, void (ObjType::*pf)(int))
{
 (o.*pf)(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write the function template as:

```
template<typename ObjType>
void ReceiveFuncPtr (ObjType o, void (ObjType::*pf)(int) )
{
   (o.*pf)(1);
}
```

This function template will automatically choose `void foo (int i)`.

---

**My previous answer (not deleting it, as it maybe helpful for others)**:

Your problem:

```
ReceiveFuncPtr(obj, &A::foo); // don't want typecast here
```

You can do this:

```
void (A::*pFun)(int) = &A::foo; // No casting here!
ReceiveFuncPtr(obj, pFun);      // No casting here!
```

`pFun` is a pointer to `void A::f(int)`

---

You can also use typedef as:

```
typedef void (A::*FunDouble)(double);
typedef void (A::*FunInt)(int);

FunInt pFun  = &A::foo;    // No casting here!
ReceiveFuncPtr(obj, pFun); // No casting here!
```

Comment: I would prefer typecasting rather than that version :). Idea is to not worrying about `A::foo` type while writing code. The template should deduce it As I suggested in the question, `any way that we can make some changes in its template parameter`

Comment: @iammilind: See my last solution. :-)

Comment: +1, that's correct. Actually I tried that but I forgot to remove the 2nd template argument `FuncPtr` which was causing error.

Comment: I recommend to not do this, because it breaks if you pass a derived class object as first and a pointer to a base class function as second argument.