# Passing a member function pointer to an overloaded class method into a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Consider this as an extension of my previous question:
[How to pass a member function pointer to an overloaded method in a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381524/how-to-pass-a-member-function-pointer-to-an-overloaded-method-in-a-template-func)

I have a function which receives pointer to class method:

```
template<typename Return, typename T>
T ReceiveFuncPtr (Return (T::*Method)(const int&))
{
  T obj;
  (obj.*Method)(1);
  return obj;
}
```

It [works fine](http://ideone.com/DtAuYk) for a handwritten class such as:

```
template<typename X, typename = void>
struct A
{
  std::pair<X,bool> foo (const X& i) { return std::pair<X,bool>(X(),true); } // choice
  void foo (std::initializer_list<X> i) { return 0; } 
};

int main ()
{
  ReceiveFuncPtr(&A<int>::foo); // OK
}
```

However, I am unable to pass `std::set<int>::insert(const int&)`

```
ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert);
```

Above statement results in:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ReceiveFuncPtr(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert); // ERROR
                                        ^   
note: candidate: template<class Return, class T> T ReceiveFuncPtr(Return (T::*)(const int&))
 T ReceiveFuncPtr (Return (T::*Method)(const int&))
   ^   
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types ‘const int&’ and ‘std::initializer_list<int>’
   ReceiveFuncPtr(&std::set<int>::insert); // ERROR
                                        ^
note:   mismatched types ‘const int&’ and ‘std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}’
note:   mismatched types ‘const int&’ and ‘std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}’
note:   mismatched types ‘const int&’ and ‘std::set<int>::value_type&& {aka int&&}’
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Return’
```

What is the correct way to pass such method?

Comment: Perhaps because your `ReceiveFuncPtr` expects a function of type `f(int)` and you're passing `f(const int&)`.

Comment: the method's signature should be `Return (T::*Method)(const int&)` and then resolved with `ReceiveFuncPtr(static_cast<std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,bool>(std::set<int>::*)(const int&)>(&std::set<int>::insert));`, but it's ugly and not portable, why are you using a function pointer instead of lambda expressions?

Comment: @iammilind http://ideone.com/VzqHWT

Comment: @PiotrS., that's a good effort again. However then the question will become of "language lawyer". You can see that it works good in the similar setup for `template class A`. Why it doesn't work in the same way for `std::set`. The additional typecast you suggested makes it work, but the code becomes verbose.

Comment: @iammilind because overloaded functions must be resolved at a call site

Comment: * (unless they can be resolved based on the signature of a function that is called which is not the case here, as template argument deduction only deduces types)

Comment: Please read the [member.functions] sections. It contains footnote 188, which says that *" the address of a member function of a class in the C ++ standard library has an unspecified type."* See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13521030/ cc @PiotrS. Forming a pointer to a member function of a StdLib type is usually not a good idea because of portability.

Comment: @dyp I said it in my first comment: *"but it's ugly and not portable*"

Comment: @PiotrS. Ah, sorry, I've only read the (good) remark about lambdas.

Comment: @PiotrS., actually I don't want to use lambdas in this specific case. Don't go by the name of the function. This function is intended to receive a standard method name e.g. `std::set<int>::insert<int>`, `std::vector<char*>::push_back()` and find our that which container it belongs to; i.e. `set` and `vector` in above cases and create an object, call the given method on it with some criteria an return the object. But now with `@dyp`'s link it seems that for standard libraries the rules are different. And I can not achieve the thing I want right now.

Comment: @dyp, I have continued the discussion by posting a new question: [Member function pointer issue with standard library methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316229/member-function-pointer-issue-with-standard-library-methods)